# Mongo return syntax error if run using --eval

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, syntax-error

When i run below mention query using mongo --eval it give "SyntaxError: Unexpected token :" but when run it using mongo shell it works fine.
Can anyone guide Why this is happening.

Mongo Command

```
mongo 127.0.0.1:27017/ne --eval "printjson(db.reader.find({  accessDate  :  { $lte : 20171122 , $gte : 20171112 }, actDate  :  { $lte : 20171122 , $gte : 20171112 } }).toArray())" > /home/output2.json
```

Output

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.3 connecting to: 127.0.0.1:27017/ne 2017-11-22T14:09:28.258+0530 SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

Comment: v2.6 passed away a year ago: https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/mongodb-2-6-end-of-life

Comment: What system shell are you using (eg. `bash`, `zsh`, ... )? I suspect you need to escape the `$` (`\$`) so they are passed through to the `mongo` shell rather than being interpreted as variables in your system shell.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me, the only issue I had was writing to the output to /home/output2.json:

```
$ mongo 127.0.0.1:27017/ne --eval "printjson(db.reader.find({  accessDate  :  { $lte : 20171122 , $gte : 20171112 }, actDate  :  { $lte : 20171122 , $gte : 20171112 } }).toArray())" > /home/output2.json
-bash: /home/output2.json: Operation not supported

$ mongo 127.0.0.1:27017/ne --eval "printjson(db.reader.find({  accessDate  :  { $lte : 20171122 , $gte : 20171112 }, actDate  :  { $lte : 20171122 , $gte : 20171112 } }).toArray())" > output2.json

$ ll output2.json
-rw-r--r--  1 myname  staff   205B Nov 22 11:53 output2.json

$ mongo --version
MongoDB shell version v3.4.7
```

What version of mongo are you using?

Comment: MongoDB shell version: 2.6.3

Comment: can you upgrade to a newer version of mongo shell and see if that solves the problem?